# Mark a question for wiki ?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, moderation, flagging

I recently asked a question on how to improve upon my existing code. I was recommended, what I was doing was the right way of doing things.

I thought of deleting the post since its not valid anymore, but then I think it can be converted to wiki. I'm not quite sure how that works.

Here is a link to it:
[Improve mouse movement in first person game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/improve-mouse-movement-in-first-person-game)

Please let me know what would be the apt action (wiki/delete etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Flagging" a question means clicking the "flag" link below a question and typing a message to the moderators.

That being said, there's no reason for that question to be CW.  If it's "not valid" because the answer says that you're doing the right thing already, then you should accept that answer and just move on.  Otherwise you should delete the question.